# First law of thermodynamics with additional term

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, energy-conservation, temperature, conservation-laws

I read in a paper that a "known expression for the heat received by a body" is $$dQ=dU+pdV-\mathbf{v}\cdot d\mathbf{P}$$

where $\mathbf{P}$ is the linear momentum of the body, $p$ is the pressure, $U$ is the internal energy, $Q$ is the heat, $V$ is the volume and $\mathbf{v}$ is the velocity.

Where did the last term come from?

Thanks

Comment: The reference is: "Einstein's comprehensive 1907 essay on relativity, part II" - Am.J.Phys.,Vol. 45, No.9, September 1977, p.815

Comment: Conversion of kinetic energy in to heat energy. Similar additional terms could be constructed for various other forms of energy (e.g. electrical or gravitational). All depends on what all terms you need to include in the free energy.